# Platform 4.0.3 x86 - How to run the emulator in phone mode at higher resolutions

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

Any idea how to run the emulator in phone mode for 720x1280 res in 4.0.3 platform?
(without using avd)

Running with the parameter: emulator-x86 -skin WXGA720 starts the emulator in tablet mode. (curiously in 4.0.4 it starts in phone mode - hardware.ini and layer files have no difference) 
Anybody has the answer?

Thanks,
Asi

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what you mean by "phone mode" and "tablet mode"? As far as I'm aware, Android makes no such distinction.

If you want to run with a custom screen resolution, you can set the resolution manually rather than using a skin name when running the emulator creation command, e.g. to get a Nexus 7-like device, where it's in portrait by default:

```
android create avd --name nexus7 --target android-16 --skin 720x1280
```

Though as there currently isn't a way to set the screen density (or other hardware properties) from the command line; if you want to do so, it's better to do this from the `android` GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At higher resolutions the platform decides if it is a phone or a tablet. emulator-x86 -skin 720X1280 also starts the emulator in tablet mode.
In tablet mode the layout is different. Notice settings application

Answer (score 0):

In platform 4.0.3, when running "emulator -skin WXGA720", for some reason the emulator does not read the hardware.ini file under development/tools/emulator/skins/WXGA720/ 
The reason that the emulator opens in tablet mode is insufficient lcd density. In hardware.ini it is set to 320 but the emulator does not interpret that and sets density to 160.
The solution that I was able to find is hacking emulator hw load properties.
in external/qemu/vl-android.c
change the line
long density = android_hw->hw_lcd_density;
to
long density = 320;

Of course at the end, make the platform.

Note: If you would like to show the system bar (the home and back buttons)
in external/qemu/android/hardware-properties.ini
set hw.mainkeys to no

Asi Mugrabi